# Is there another word for being too nice?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

What are different words that can/could/would be used to describe someone who is being too nice?

Comment: Answered at [Is there a word for being so polite as to appear insincere?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147642/is-there-a-word-for-being-so-polite-as-to-appear-insincere)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *nice*, I suppose. And also *too*. Niceness is multidimensional, in terms of the types of behavior it would involve.

Comment: too nice might also mean too forgiving or too lenient, too generous, or too indulgent.  You do need to narrow it down where and under what circumstances you want to use the word.

Answer (score 3):

**saccharine**.

As in ridiculously over optimistic or agreeable, to a degree that strays into parody.

Ref [urbandictionary term:saccharine](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=saccharine)